# Technology behind the ZPM and Gravity Gun

Tags: video-games, stargate, technology, artificial-gravity, half-life

Does anyone know if the [Zero Point Energy gun](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Point_Energy_Field_Manipulator) and the [Zero Point Module](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Point_Module) are related? Do they operate on similar technologies? (I think they both use gravity, but in different forms) It would also be interesting to know if the people that came up with the idea for one got the inspiration from the other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea about the ZPM is that it operates by tapping into a theoretical energy that permeates everything, known as the [Zero Point Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy). It's well known to exist, and has even been proven, but the ability to exploit it is in serious doubt. This same theoretical energy source is what powers the Zero Point Energy Gun, and a whole host of other technologies from games, movies, and books.

Answer (score 12):

Possible, but unlikely.  "Zero point" is a reference to a property of quantum systems.  Sci-fi writers use it as a magic device basically, as the idea goes that if you could tap into zero point energy and harvest what would potentially be infinite energy.  However, this would violate the laws of physics as we know it, so it's magic at present.

For more information, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy#Claims_in_pseudoscience).